# Why methods for streams are not declared as default in java api?

Tags: java, methods, interface, java-stream

I'm new to streams and as I understand this returns a stream:

```
IntStream.range(0, 20).skip(10)
```

IntStream is an interface and has this in default section of java api:

```
static IntStream range(int startInclusive,
                       int endExclusive)
```

However,

```
IntStream skip(long n)
```

is not shown to be declared as default in java api, even though it clearly has an implementation.

Could someone please elaborate why?

Comment: *"It clearly has an implementation"*: where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand. `IntStream` is an interface. The actual implementation is therefore up to... whatever classes decide to stick an `implements IntStream` at the end of it. Such a class is called an 'IntStream implementation'. An IntStream implementation is free to implement the skip method, and the whole concept of an int stream, in whatever way it wants.

The problem is that you can't speak of *THE* implementation of IntStream `skip`. You can only speak of *AN* implementation of IntStream `skip`. It would be weird to hardcode some implementation of skip as the default implementation, especially considering that you wouldn't be able to write it: How would you implement a skip method that works for any IntStream regardless of how IntStream works?

default impls generally are designed to work with other (non-defaulted) methods as basic building blocks. For example, java 8 added the following method to `java.util.Map` (which is an interface): `getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)`, which is implemented in terms of map's `get` method and map's `containsKey` method, both of which have no default implementation (they are building blocks; to be a map, you have to implement these).

Those basic building blocks? Those don't have default implementations; that is the point: an implementation of such an interface needs to provide implementations of each such building block method, and the remaining methods (the defaulted ones) will just work, based on those building blocks, but if you want to implement those too, for example because you can do it more efficiently, feel free.

Which leaves the final issue: Is `skip` a 'building block' or more complex 'built on building blocks' kind of method? The authors decided it is a building block, and implementing it by reading elements one at a time and discarding them until X elements have been discarded felt too much like obviously inferior.

Why did they make that choice? You'd have to ask the author, that kind of detailed discussion is, as far as I know, not covered during the public debates which you can follow for example on mailing lists like [lambda-dev](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/lambda-dev).

NB: The `range` method you mention is static. static methods are like named constructors: That method requires no context or existing stream at all: Instead it creates a new `IntStream` which streams through the range. It produces one particular implementation of the `IntStream` interface; many others exist, and how it implements `skip` doesn't necessarily apply to other takes on intstream implementations.

Comment: So IntStream.range(0, 20) returns an IntStream that has a skip() implementation?

Comment: @zzzz11222333 Yes, that's correct.